# How do I solve $\ \lim_{{x\to1}} \left(\log_{5}5x\right)^{\log_{x}5} $?

Tags: limits, logarithms

How do I solve with the logarithm in the exponent?

$$ \lim_{{x\to1}} \left(\log_{5}5x\right)^{\log_{x}5}$$

I'm not adept enough to understand how to deal with it.

---

My approach

$$\lim_{x\to1}\left(\log_{5}5x\right)^{\log_{x}5}=\lim_{x\to1}e^{\log_{x}5\log\left(\log_{5}5x\right)}=e^{\lim_{x\to1}\log_{x}5\log\left(\log_{5}5x\right)}$$

- LHL

$$\lim_{x\to1^-}\log_{x}5\log\left(\log_{5}5x\right) =e^1=e$$

- RHL

$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\log_{x}5\log\left(\log_{5}5x\right) =e^1=e$$

or

$$e^{\lim_{x\to1}\log_{x}5\left(\log_{5}5x-1\right)} =e^{\lim_{x\to1}\log_{x}5\left(\log_{5}5 +\log_5 x-1\right)}=e^{\lim_{x\to1}\log_{x}5\log_5 x}=e^1=e$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: in this one? nothing really. It went over my head, have 2 or 3 similar doubts that i dont understand at all. Also, hello again. Will decide whether to post the other doubts or not if this one gets cleared

Comment: Try L'Hôpital's rule? It is indeterminate form $1^\infty$

Comment: @Tim via l hopital's it comes as e. But i want an alternate way

Comment: @SamarthSaluja Can you show your work with l'Hospital?

Comment: @user nvm. on taking ln for the above eqn and taking limits from both left and right hand side it is observed that when x tends to 1, f(x) tends to 1. Hence e^1. Thank you for your time and efforts yet again, i hadn't considered this way until now

Comment: @SamarthSaluja If you show your work we can check that and give you some advice.

Comment: @user https://photos.app.goo.gl/XBu85oac1u5X5Vk86

Comment: @SamarthSaluja I've typed your solution in LaTex, please modify if I've misinterpreted some step.

Comment: @user thanks for doing that. The solution seems fine to me. You're an angel, thanks for your time and effort dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{{x\to1}} \left(\log_{5}5x\right)^{\log_{x}5} &= \lim_{x \to 1} \left( \log_5 5+\log_5 x \right)^{\log_x 5}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 1} \left( 1+ \frac{1}{\log_x 5} \right)^{\log_x 5}\\
&= \lim_{t \to \infty} \left( 1+ \frac{1}{t}\right)^{t}\quad,\quad t = \log_{x}5 \to \infty\;\text{ as }\;x\to1\\
&= e
\end{align*}

Comment: Very nice solution! (+1)

Comment: Some Semantical Metamathematical logic: Of course, we have to have a tree which is 't' ( baby says a tree as tee) above, when 'log' s are in involvement correct :-) ? the above statement is as trees approaches infinity, say they grow a lot.. One +1 bite (extra bite) powers a tree as well !  we have to eat them to be healthy to grow more of them. for approaching 'e'  ( e is 'fly' in tamil)  for approaching flight ..... Of course you cut  their  base ( base 'x' & logs them to 5 pieces so $t = log_x ^5$. 1 cut they grow!   ...Just thought how meaning makes sense in two symbolic languages at once!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the very fine solution given, your way to start is fine with

$$\left(\log_{5}5x\right)^{\log_{x}5}=e^{\log_{x}5\log\left(\log_{5}5x\right)}$$

but not the conclusion since $\log_{x}5\log\left(\log_{5}5x\right)$ is in the form $\infty\cdot 0$.

From here we can instead proceed as follows by

$$\log_{5}5x= \frac{\log 5x}{\log 5}, \;\;\; \log_{x}5=\frac{\log 5}{\log x} $$

then

$$\left(\log_{5}5x\right)^{\log_{x}5}=e^{\log_{x}5\log\left(\log_{5}5x\right)}=e^{\frac{\log 5}{\log x}\left(\log\log (5x)-\log\log 5\right)}\to e$$

indeed by l'Hospital (very useful in this case)

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\log\log (5x)-\log\log 5}{\log x}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\frac{1}{\log 5x}}{\frac1x} \to \frac{1}{\log 5}$$

Comment: Noted thank you